# $\sigma$-Compactness--Is this Union Actually Countable?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group. The union of countably many open $\sigma$-compact subgroups of $G$ generates an open $\sigma$-compact subgroup.

For each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, let $L_n = \bigcup_{j=1} K_{n,j}$ be an open subgroup, where $K_{n,j}$ is compact. I was able to prove that $\langle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty L_n \rangle = \langle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_{n,j} \rangle$ is open; and I'm pretty certain it's true that

$$\langle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty L_n \rangle = \bigcup_{t=1}^\infty \bigcup_{(n_1,...,n_t),(j_1,...,j_t) \in \Bbb{N}^k} K_{n_1,j_1} ... K_{n_t,j_t}$$

It's clear that $K_{n_1,j_1} ... K_{n_t,j_t}$ is compact. However, it isn't clear that that nasty double union is a single countable union of compact sets. How does one argue for that conclusion?

Comment: Countable union of countable sets is countable. You can enumerate them by listing them along diagonals like this $\swarrow\swarrow\swarrow$. The first few terms of a listing a sequence of sequences $x_{i,j}$ in a single sequence would be $x_{1,1},x_{1,2},x_{2,1},x_{1,3},x_{2,2},x_{3,1},...$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but I think the equality in the middle is wrong. I think that you don't count the products of elements within the same compact set (I mean, what about elements in $K_{1,1}^2$?)

Comment: It seems correct, except that you need to include inverses if you want to have the group generated by this set and not the semigroup, so you should write $K_{n, j}^{\pm 1}$ instead. That "nasty double union" is countable: the second one is countable for any $k$, since it is the union over the countable set $(\mathbb{N}^k)^2$, and then you're taking countably many of those.

Comment: @Yanko the user is considering $k$-tuples in \mathbb{N}^k: repetitions are allowed.